# React: pass Api data to an array | Undefined' is not assignable to type 'GridRowsProp'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, react-hooks, syntax-error

I'm trying to pass data from an api, by using map() to an array. The reason is to show the data inside a tabel with rows. I'm using material UI table.

```
const array1 = data?.interface_here;

const map2 = array1?.map(x => ({ id: x.id, customer_name: x.customer_name, appointment: x.appointment, amount: x.amount }));

//This is how the data-grid wants me to do it
const rows = [
  { id: 1, customer_name: "y", appointment: '12:30', amount: 35 },
  { id: 2, customer_name: "w", appointment: '12:30', amount: 35 },
];

console.log(rows);

console.log(map2);
// {id: 30, customer_name: "Hello", appointment: "19.05.2021", amount: 650}

  return (
    <Body>
      <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid rows={map2} columns={columns} pageSize={5} checkboxSelection />
    </div>
```

But when i try to change rows={rows} to rows={map2} , i get Error:
Type '{ id: number; customer_name: String; appointment: String; amount: number; }[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'GridRowsProp'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'GridRowData[]'.  TS2322

Result example:
[Image of console result, first is example, second is api data after pushing data into map2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA2np.png)

Comment: Could you please add a complete example?

Comment: Provided a image with console.log result and changed code to how it is now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const map2 = array1?.map(x => ({ id: x.id, customer_name: x.customer_name, appointment: x.appointment, amount: x.amount }));
```

You are using optional chaining to defer handling the possibly undefined value of `array1`. That means the potential `undefined`-ness gets passed on to `map2`, whose type signature will look something like:

```js
{id: number; customer_name: string; appointment: string; amount: number}[] | undefined
```

You either need to default it to some sane value (`map2 ?? []`), or tell typescript that you *know* this value won't be `undefined`: `map2!`. I don't typically recommend the latter as the compiler is doing its job correctly when it complains about the value.